# How do I access an Ember.js model item without using a forEach

Tags: ember.js

Usually I have to do this to access items:

```
setupController: function (controller, model) {
      this._super(controller, model);      
      model.accounts.forEach(function (account) {
            data.push(account.get("item"));

          });
}
```

Instead I just want to access the 1st item like this but it returns undefined:

```
  model.accounts[0]
```

Edit__

accounts come like so in the route:

```
 model: function () {

      return Ember.RSVP.hash({
        main: this.store.createRecord('main', {}),
        accounts: this.store.find('account')
      });
    },
```

Comment: `model.get('accounts').firstObject` should work.

Comment: undefined when I do that in my route's setupController method

Comment: Well, then, your model does not have an `accounts` property, or the `accounts` property is empty, at least not at the time you are trying to access it. Where is it supposed to come from, and at what point in time does it get assigned to the model, and are you sure it is populated? If `accounts` is an asynch hasMany relationship, it will not be populated automatically at this point in time.

Comment: ok so as you see in my edit its async, so I guess I should set up an observer in the controller?

Comment: `model.get('accounts[0]')` or `model.get('accounts.[0]')` should do the trick. If you want to get it inside setupcontroller you probably doing something wrong

Comment: @MateuszNowak how would you set up your controller with different properties derived from the RSVP hash on the route?

Comment: I could use observes on the controller but it doesn't feel right just to set up initial properties..

Comment: You can use `Ember.computed.alias('accounts.firstObject')` inside controller or try setup property using afterModel method on route.

Comment: trying the latter now..

Comment: first of all this.store.find() returns you a promise so your undefined comes from that the promise was not fulfilled. and wheres does "data" var from data.push comes from ?

Answer (score 2):

You can create an array proxy.
Then you'll have a property called firstObject and a lot of other methods built in from ember.

myArray.get('firstObject')

Here's an example:
http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayProxy.html

Comment: My accounts model has already come from the store. Why do I need to wrap it and a proxy?  **accounts: this.store.find('account')**

Comment: have you tried.
model.get('accounts').get('firstObject');